# please explain to me how i could better code this out

Tags: python

> You have been asked to make a special book categorization program, which assigns each book a special code based on its title.
> The code is equal to the first letter of the book, followed by the number of characters in the title.
> For example, for the book "Harry Potter", the code would be: H12, as it contains 12 characters (including the space).
>
> You are provided a books.txt file, which includes the book titles, each one written on a separate line.
> Read the title one by one and output the code for each book on a separate line.
>
> For example, if the books.txt file contains:
>
> ```
> Some book
> Another book
> ```
>
> Your program should output:
>
> ```
> S9
> A12
> ```
>
> Recall the readlines() method, which returns a list containing the lines of the file.
> Also, remember that all lines, except the last one, contain a \n at the end, which should not be included in the character count.

---

This is a website I'm using to learn python and
I am stuck because i don't know where to use `readlines()` and I don't really know why I need to use it. (It has to be used.) My code below shows me printing every name in the file and only getting its first letter. My mistake is when I run this code I get the same exact thing I wanted except my last digit is off because of spaces.

```
#given code
file = open("/usercode/files/books.txt", "r")

#my code

for name in file:
    
    print(name[0] + str(len(name)-1))

file.close()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Your Output
H12
T16
P19
G17
Expected Output
H12
T16
P19
G18
```

Comment: You can use `name.strip()` to remove any leading and trailing whitespace from each line.

Comment: If you're required to use `readlines()`, use `for name in file.readlines():`

Comment: You don't need `readlines` for this example. A file object iterates the lines of the file and you are using it correctly in the `for` loop. You could do `lines = file.readlines()` and then `for line in lines:`, but that's not as good as what you are already doing.

Comment: @Barmar when i do this i get an error with my file.close() it says invalid syntax

Comment: @0x5453 when i remove str(len(name)-1) and put what you said, it just doubles the first charcater. it makes it HHarry potter instead of Harry potter

Comment: @privateprinceton You probably left out a `)` on the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions say:

> Also, remember that all lines, **except the last one**, contain a \n at the end

You're subtracting 1 from the length of all lines, including the last one.

Instead of subtracting 1 from the length and special-casing the last line, you can use the `rstrip()` method to remove a newline at the end of the string.

```
for name in file.readlines():
    print(name[0] + str(len(name.rstrip('\n'))))
```

Comment: I get that the question includes a hint about "readlines", but also note that its not the right way to iterate files for anyone using this example in the future.

Comment: I suspect the instructor expected them to read the lines into a list, then check whether the index == len(lines)-1 to decide whether to subtract 1.

Comment: when i do this i get an error with my file.close() it says invalid syntax

Comment: I had a missing `)`

Comment: another question, is r.strip used only to remove whitespaces at the end of a word/sentence?

Comment: It removes whitespace at the end by default. But if you give it an argument, it removes any of the characters in that collection.